# Tensor product of complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and let the modules that are involved be left and right $A$-modules (not necessarily bimodules over $A$).

I'll denote as $\mathcal{E}^n_R(M, N)$ the category of $n$-fold extensions of $M$ by $N$, and as $\otimes$ the tensor product of chain complexes. Under what hypothesis have I the following restriction?

$$\otimes:\mathcal{E}^n_R(A, A)\times \mathcal{E}^m_R(A, A)\to \mathcal{E}^{m+n}_R(A, A)$$

And in an arbitrary abelian/additive category?